# how can android app's one user send notifications to multiple users of same android app?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

When app's one user creates goal and allocates to multiple users they should get notification on goal creation.
Which method should be used? How can this be done?

Comment: look at this https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: This can be achieved by GCM push notification. Procedure is like all the devices who're using your app should register for GCM and those registration ID should be stored in your user table in server database having different column. When you are creating a goal and add users to them, you should call the web-service which will send push notifications to the registered devices based on user id. Hope you understand.

Comment: thanks..Is there any web service like this which can send push notification.